# Javascript fade out effect cannot make the image disappear

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can make the fade out effect on the image, however, after the effect, the image still shows on the screen. I want to make it `display: none;` after the 2s fade out effect. How can it be done?

```js
document.getElementById("imgX").style.animation = "fadeout 2s";
```

```css
@keyframes fadeout {
    from { opacity: 1; }
    to   { opacity: 0; }
}

         /* Firefox < 16 */
@-moz-keyframes fadeout {
    from { opacity: 1; }
    to   { opacity: 0; }
}

/* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeout {
    from { opacity: 1; }
    to   { opacity: 0; }
}

/* Internet Explorer */
@-ms-keyframes fadeout {
    from { opacity: 1; }
    to   { opacity: 0; }
}

/* Opera < 12.1 */
@-o-keyframes fadeout {
    from { opacity: 1; }
    to   { opacity: 0; }
}
```

```html
<img id="imgX" src="x.png" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `forwards`

```
document.getElementById("imgX").style.animation = "fadeout 2s forwards";
```

Answer (score 2):

## Add [`forwards`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode) to your animation declaration

```js
document.getElementById("imgX").style.animation = "fadeout 2s forwards";
```

```css
@keyframes fadeout {
    from { opacity: 1; }
    to   { opacity: 0; }
}

         /* Firefox < 16 */
@-moz-keyframes fadeout {
    from { opacity: 1; }
    to   { opacity: 0; }
}

/* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeout {
    from { opacity: 1; }
    to   { opacity: 0; }
}

/* Internet Explorer */
@-ms-keyframes fadeout {
    from { opacity: 1; }
    to   { opacity: 0; }
}

/* Opera < 12.1 */
@-o-keyframes fadeout {
    from { opacity: 1; }
    to   { opacity: 0; }
}
```

```html
<img id="imgX" src="x.png" />
```